# Why can I access the return value of useFetch without await keyword?

Tags: nuxt.js

## Problem

I'm using Nuxt3.

`useFetch` usage is like this:

```
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch('...')
```

However, I also can use `data`, `pending`, `error`, and `refresh` like this:

```
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = useFetch('...')
```

When `const response = useFetch('...')`, `response instanceof Promise` is `true` so the return value should be `Promise` or the sub classes.

I do not know the behavior so could you tell me why?

## Env

- nuxt: 3.6.5

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing, and here is what I found, but I just looked at this in the last 5 minutes.

If you look at the implementation of useFetch in nuxt3, you will see first that is not an async function. It uses useAsyncData under the hood, again not an async function, which does the following in the last three lines:

```
const asyncDataPromise = Promise.resolve(nuxt._asyncDataPromises[key]).then(() => asyncData);
Object.assign(asyncDataPromise, asyncData);
return asyncDataPromise;
```

Meaning it "mixes" a promise with the reactive properties you know (asyncData has the properties data, pending, status, error, ...), so you can either use await (i.e. the promise) or not, and more or less get the same behavior. Apparently some frameworks use that trick to make using async (or not) easier and more lenient.

Answer (score -1):

`useFetch()` returns a Promise, allowing you to wait for its values to be ready. `await` (or a [`then()` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), for that matter) waits for the promise to resolve and returns the values directly.

When you run this:

```
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch('...')
```

you are getting a Promise from `useFetch` and waiting for it to resolve via `await` to get the values directly, while

```
const x = useFetch('...')
```

skips the await step and just saves the Promise you can await or use later on in the code.

You can read more about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) on MDN.

Comment: Thank you but yours is not an answer to the question. I know about `Promise` and `await`.